# How to display multiple items under 1 category name?

Tags: python, html, django, sqlite

views.py :

```py
def gerechten(request):
    template = loader.get_template('café/gerechten.html')
    mydata = gerecht_info.objects.all()
    mydata2 = gerechten_Categorie.objects.all()

    context = {
        'mygerecht': mydata,
        'mycategories': mydata2
    }   
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

models.py :

```py
class gerechten_Categorie(models.Model):
    categorie = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.categorie

class gerecht_info(models.Model):
    categorie = models.ForeignKey(gerechten_Categorie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gerecht_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    gerecht_description = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    gerecht_price = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.gerecht_name
    def drinkdesc(self):
        return self.gerecht_description
    def drinkprice(self):
        return self.gerecht_price
```

gerechten.html :

```
{% if mygerecht %}
{% for cat in mygerecht %}
<div class="flex">
    <div class="menu-head center">
        <h2>{{cat.categorie}}</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
        <ul class="price">
            <li>{{cat.gerecht_name}}</li>
            <li>€{{cat.gerecht_price}}</li>
        </ul>
        {% if cat.gerecht_description %}
        <p>{{cat.gerecht_description}}</p>
        {% else %}
        <p></p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
<div class="menu-head center">
<h2>no items avaible</h2>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrhhs.png) but I want all info from 'Hapjes' into 1 'Hapjes' category, not separated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are trying to achieve can be done with [`regroup` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup).

```html
{% regroup mygerecht by categorie as article_categories %}
{% for categorie in article_categories %}
<div class="flex">
    <div class="menu-head center">
        <h2>{{categorie.grouper}}</h2>
    </div>
    {% for article in categorie.list %}
    <div class="menu-item">
        <ul class="price">
            <li>{{article.gerecht_name}}</li>
            <li>€{{article.gerecht_price}}</li>
        </ul>
        <p>{% if article.gerecht_description %}{{article.gerecht_description}}{% endif %}</p>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: nope, i just tried it and it isnt changing the order. it still looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrhhs.png

Comment: @subjoel are you sure you updated your code ? I just tried it and it is showing every item in its categorie on my side

Comment: https://ibb.co/6BzNCcn

Comment: let me try again

Comment: it works now, i forgot to reload templates. tysm man.